# QT application crashes when QWebFrame's evaluatingJavascript method called

Tags: multithreading, qt, boost, qthread, qtwebkit

I am using a **QWebFrame** to visualize some data and I use **evalueateJavascript** method to update data on Javascript. Here is my function to do this.

```
QWebFrame * webFrame;
void setValue(int idx, double value){

   webPage->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(QString("setDataValue(%1,%2)").arg(QString::number(idx)).arg(QString::number(value)));   
}
```

In QT application I can call this function via a button call back as many time without causing an error.

I want to call this **setValue** function from a separate thread to visualize incoming data. When I call setValue function from a **separate thread**, after few or first iteration **application crash**. I tried with both QThread and boost threads, but results are same.

```
void dummyTest(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    setValue(0,rand() % 150);
}
```

This dummyTest function is also working without problems when called via a button callback, but **crash on running on a separate thread**.

Here is the code for thread initialization

```
 void startSerialProcessing() {
     boost::thread_attributes attr;
     attr.set_stack_size(1024);

     std::cout << "dummy processor started. \n";
     serialThread= new boost::thread(&MavLinkAL::dummyTest, this);
 }
```

My observation is **this crash only happens when setValue is called from a separate thread**. Here is important lines from coredump file viewed from gdb.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

#0  0x00007f3f0d6f361f in WTF::StringImpl::~StringImpl() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
#1  0x00007f3f0d6583f8 in JSC::JSValue::toStringSlowCase(JSC::ExecState*) const
    () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
#2  0x00007f3f0d68a396 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
#3  0x00007f3f0d55a9f1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
#4  0x00007f3f0d56313f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
```

Any help to solve this problem is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWebFrame` functions are neither reentrant nor thread safe. They can only be invoked from main GUI thread. Qt allows you to deliver a message to another thread quite easily. Make `setValue` function a slot, and connect it to a signal emitted from the processing thread.

**EDIT**: As Vladimir Bershov suggested in the comment below, one can also use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` to achieve the same result.

Comment: He can also use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) with [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) connection type

Comment: @Dinesh, could you mark this as answer in that case? ;)